# Colabs File Transfer Not to Drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm looking at a software package called [nmrglue](https://nmrglue.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and I'm using colabs as an ipython notebook.

To install the software you need to ...

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
```

afterwards you copy the [nmrglue-X.X.tar.gz](https://github.com/jjhelmus/nmrglue/releases/download/v0.7/nmrglue-0.7.tar.gz) file and put it in the colabs folder, /content.

At the moment I copy that to my laptop and transfer that to the colabs folder by dragging from the downloads folder with my mouse.

There must be some code around to do that automatically?  Can anyone suggest any?

(There are lots of colab moving data files questions and answers but they all tend to be to and from the user's google Drive account.  That's not what I want to do).

Comment: Is the file available for download somewhere on the internet? If you provide the link I can give you the code to download it.

Comment: @rchurt here's the first one https://github.com/jjhelmus/nmrglue/releases/download/v0.7/nmrglue-0.7.tar.gz (I'm sure I'll be able to modify the code) which I want to put in the folder /content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple,

```
!wget https://github.com/jjhelmus/nmrglue/releases/download/v0.7/nmrglue-0.7.tar.gz
```

This puts the file in the /contents folder.

I can subsequently unzip it etc...